# During jQuery Animation, top level UL element disappears

Tags: jquery, animation, menu, drop-down-menu

I have a nested set of unordered lists that I'm using for a dropdown menu structure:

UL > LI > DIV > UL > LI * n > A

I'm using jQuery to animate the dropdown/display of the div and child ul:

```
jQuery('ul.top-ul li.top-li').hover(function() {
          jQuery(this).animate({height:"150px"},200);
          jQuery(this).find('div').animate({height:"150px"},4000, function() {
              jQuery('ul.top-ul li.top-li div p').fadeIn('fast');
          });
      }, function() {
          jQuery('ul.top-ul li.top-li div p').fadeOut('fast');
          jQuery(this).animate({height:"22px"},200);
          jQuery(this).find('div').animate({height:"0px"},200);
      })
```

When this animation runs, however, the UL directly under the div disappears until the animation has run its course.

This is viewable at http://acldev.com/rsac/index.php (I've slowed the animation WAY down just to emphasize the point.

What's causing UL to disappear? When I stop animating the DIV, the UL doesn't disappear.

Comment: Im facing the same problem. How did you fix it?

Comment: I didn't end up fixing it. The client decided to do a standard drop down menu. I would love to look into this again though. It's based on the CSS3 drop down menu.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm not using it in a menu

Answer (score 0):

Your menu is dissapearing because of this selector `jQuery(this).find('div').animate...` in your third line.

Try using something like `jQuery(this).find('.maincats ul').animate...` to explicitly make appear and disappear the nested lists.

Hope it helps.